# ERROR: flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception

Tags: dart, flutter

My app working fine all http service work well. Suddenly something happens[image] and now showing this error to any of my http service.

trying dig into the problem but failed.

Thank for any help

Comment: run `flutter doctor -v` and re-run the app

Comment: I had a same error, My issue was I used wrong method for call web service , As example I used client.get()  but correct one for my case is client.post()

Comment: Check your internet connectivity.